# Multiple Precondition failed annotation using swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

I'm using [swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to document my web api project and I cannot add multiple responses for precondition failed cases, swagger only shows the last one.

```
/// <response code="200">OK</response>
/// <response code="401">Unauthorized</response>
/// <response code="400">BadRequest</response>
/// <response code="412">ErrorCode = 1... </response>
/// <response code="412">ErrorCode = 2... </response>
/// <response code="412">ErrorCode = 3... </response>
```

Swashbuckle generates something like:

```
{
  ...
  "responses": {
    "200": {
      "description": "OK"
    },
    "400": {
      "description": "BadRequest"
    },
    "401": {
      "description": "Unauthorized"
    },
    "412": {
      "description": "ErrorCode = 3..."
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Where I would like to see:

```
{
  ...
  "412": {
    "description": "ErrorCode = 1..."
  },
  "412": {
    "description": "ErrorCode = 2..."
  },
  "412": {
    "description": "ErrorCode = 3..."
  }
}
```

Any thoughts about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with Swashbuckle because it is not compliant with the Open API specification (aka Swagger). The responses object contains a list of possible responses. Each response has a name and a [response object](http://swagger.io/specification/#responseObject). The name can be `default` or a HTTP status code. According to the spec of a [responses object](http://swagger.io/specification/#responsesObject) there can be only one response object per status code:

> Any HTTP status code can be used as the property name (**one property per HTTP status code**). Describes the expected response for that HTTP status code.

That being said, I doubt whether it is correct to add additional error codes to a 412 response. A conditional request might not reach your server in case a proxy server already knows the conditions won't be matched.

Comment: Thanks @venerik, following your answer I end up having a single error code entry with all possible cases in the description fields and enhancing the swagger-ui having an IOperationFilter to display newlines per error.